# Where unsubscribe from model changes in view?

Tags: android, observer-pattern

I have this custom view:

```
public class OrderProductDetail extends LinearLayout implements OrderProductListener {

       TextView description;

       public void bind(OrderProduct product) {
           this.product = product;
           product.addChangesListener(this);
           description.setText(product.getDescription());
       }

       //more stuff    

       @Override //method of OrderProductListener interface
       public void onStateChanged(OrderProduct object) {
           //do something
       }

}
```

Where should I unsubscribe (call `OrderProduct.removeChangesListener()`) the view from `OrderProduct` changes? In the `onDetachedFromWindow` method?

In an activity I'd do it in `onDestroy` method.